# Combine Serilog logs with built-in Microsoft .NET Core loggers

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, windows-services, serilog

I have a Windows Service written in .NET Core 6 and have been using the default logging solution, including Microsoft's Event Log logger extension, which is working well. My current `Program.cs` which sets up the host and changes the Event Log's source name is:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;
using System;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "My Super Service";
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.Configure<EventLogSettings>(settings =>
            settings.SourceName = "My Super Service");
        services.AddSingleton<SomeOtherServiceHere>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

I use `ILogger` Dependency Injection in the service's `Worker` class and my `SomeOtherServiceHere` code without issue.

My `appsettings.json` includes setting the Event Log's `LogLevel` to `Information` just so I can see some startup info during testing:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Microsoft doesn't include a file-based logger in .NET Core, so I've added Serilog into the mix. The file logger and console logger are working, but I'm not seeing Event Log entries any more from the Microsoft logger.

The addition to my `Program.cs` `CreateBuilder` call is:

```
    .UseSerilog((context, config) => config
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console())
```

I've added a new `Serilog` section to my `appsettings.json` to configure the file log:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "path": "./logs/log.txt", "rollingInterval": "Day" }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is it possible to use Microsoft's extension for Event Log logging and Serilog for everything else? Or is it recommended that I abandon this approach and use the Serilog Event Log Sink instead? I'm a little reticent to do this because configuring it via `appsettings.json` is under-documented and I'd rather not change what's already working.

Comment: You can use a Serilog Sink for that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/

Comment: @Fildor Thanks. I'm aware of the Serilog Event Log sink, but would like to avoid using it in this instance because I have a solution which already works with the Microsoft logging extension. I'm hoping that choosing Serilog isn't all-or-nothing and it is capable of mixing with other providers.